# Unreal Engine - Materials Import as Gray

Tags: textures, unreal-4, models, 3d-meshes, materials

I imported the .fbx files from here: https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/industrial/other/big-warehouse-pack
into an Unreal Engine 4.27 project. All the meshes load in properly, but the materials are all gray. So I just have a bunch of gray shelves, boxes, etc...

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what happened, but I found a bunch of png files in a different folder, and some more fbx files in another one. I then combined the contents of all the folders, and imported them altogether at once, and it worked. I think the png files are used as textures for the materials associated to the meshes, which makes the models have their proper appearance.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, you could mark it as accepted.